# SharePoint List schema for PowerApps for a table with multiple data types

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, sharepoint-list, powerapps-canvas

I am a newbie to power apps. I have a data with different numeric data types in a column as given in the image.

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tjvS.png)

I want create a power apps with the data on the table as database. I will be using SharePoint list as a database. Could you please help me on how I can add this to SharePoint as one column has different numeric data types and as far as I know we can only add one numeric data type to a column in SP list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you are looking for are not directly concercing PowerApps rather sharepoint column (data types). I belive you have already looked into google.

Take a look at [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/list-and-library-column-types-and-options-0d8ddb7b-7dc7-414d-a283-ee9dca891df7) this explains all the column type and also which to be used when.

You can easily connect to sharepoint in PowerApps as out of box connector.

Comment: I understand that. But from the image you can see, there are multiple numeric data types in one column. But in SharePoint list I was able to select only one numeric data type for a column. 

I added power apps because I thought someone may have had this scenario while creating an app with SP list as db and they maybe able to help.

Comment: using powerapps you can append/show numeric with column with your percentage or so on. But to get your point you have to choose column type defined in sharepoint there is no special column which would be useful, unless you use Text column and then convert this text to numeric if you want to perfrom any mathematical calcualtions. Please mark this as solved if it helps.